# css and js should have relative path in page source - magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

I have one request that is **I need to change all the css & js path from absolute to relative in page source**.

Please refer the screenshot for your easy reference. here I want to change all the css ans js to relative path.

[image: screenshot for your easy reference]

For example I need to change

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://172.17.0.2/pub/static/frontend/Gworks/Home/en_US/mage/calendar.css" />
```

To

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="/pub/static/frontend/Gworks/Home/en_US/mage/calendar.css" />
```

how to achieve this?

**note :** Suppose if this not best practice or not possible, please mention the valid reason in your answers.

Comment: is this in your theme layout or module?

Comment: @belfort1 I am asking generally, when u see your magento-2 source code (CTRL+U), all the css and js declare with full absolute path I need to change that to relative path. Still you can't get please feel free to mention in comment I will update again.

Comment: ok, had misunderstood your question,  the urls for css are processed in: Magento\Framework\View\Url\CssResolver